# Excel - Using Sheet2 equations to calculate multiple scenarios on Sheet1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have setup Sheet2 to have 3 input fields (cells) and a number of equations calculate the result. There a some intermediate steps, lookup tables, etc..

Let's say my input on Sheet2 is

```
Param1 goes in cell A1, Param2-A2, Param3-A3, Result-A5
```

Now I would like to take Sheet1 that has rows of data sets that need to be calculated by the same process.

```
Row 1 would have aParam1, aParam2, aParam3, aResult1
Row 2 would have bParam1, bParam2, bParam3, bResult1
......
```

Is there a way to have Excel plugin the Param1,2,3 values into Sheet2, get the result and write it back to Sheet1? Doing this for multiple rows, re-using the Sheet2 calculations.

I suppose I can do it in VBA, by copying values over in sets and getting the result, but is there a non-VBA approach?

Comment: Instead of writing something like =A1+A2 in sheet 1, and having excel take A1 and A2 from itself, you can write =Sheet2!A1+Sheet2!A2 and it will use the values from sheet 2 instead. Clicking and dragging a formula works exactly the same way, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy way to re-use a formula set based upon given parameters (that exist in a different sheet) and return a result. You do something similar every time you use a built in Function in excel's normal Function list.

You can define a custom function very quickly in VBA to do what you are wanting.
Here is a quick example of how a custom function is defined.
It has a few parts: the function definition, the variables as input, the output data type and finally the returning of data from the function to the Excel sheet when called.

```
Function calcit(base as Long, par1 As Long, par2 As Long, par3 as Long) As Long
   ' {YOUR MATH FORMULA HERE BASED UPON THE RELATIONSHIP FOR base, par1,par2,par3}

   calcit = '{Replace with OUTPUT: returns the math variable from above to the formula}  ' this section is what returns the 'calc it' function to the Excel sheet.

End Function
```